# Draw background color on specific page in app

Tags: java, android, canvas, background

I have a problem, I`m begginer in programming so please explain me as simple as posible :)

I have this code, which show level menu (user tap on number of level), but I want to draw specific background color just on this view.

Is there any way?

```
//levelmenu stuff________________________________________________________________________________
    level_circles_border_dp = dpToPx(level_circles_border);

    int circles_in_x = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Brick_Pattern.length));
    int circles_in_y = (int) Math.ceil((float) Brick_Pattern.length / (float) circles_in_x);
    int radius = (int) (((ScreenWidth() - ((float) level_circles_border_dp * (float) (circles_in_x + 1))) / (float) circles_in_x) / 2);

    int total_circles_height = (circles_in_y * ((radius * 2) + level_circles_border_dp)) + level_circles_border_dp;

    int current_lvl = 1;
    for (int y = 0; y < circles_in_y; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < circles_in_x; x++) {
            if (current_lvl <= Brick_Pattern.length)
                Level_Buttons[current_lvl - 1] = new level_button("" + current_lvl, (int) (radius / 3.0f), FORTE, getResources().getColor(R.color.black), level_circles_border_dp + (x * ((radius * 2) + level_circles_border_dp)), (ScreenHeight() / 2) - (total_circles_height / 2) + (level_circles_border_dp + (y * ((radius * 2) + level_circles_border_dp))), radius, getResources().getColor(R.color.white), this, false, SubTitle_Paint);
            current_lvl++;
        }
```

### }

```
        if (state == MENU) {
        //draw title
        Rect Title_Paint_bounds = new Rect();
        Title_Paint.getTextBounds(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), 0, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name).length(), Title_Paint_bounds);
        canvas.drawText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), (ScreenWidth() / 2) - (Title_Paint_bounds.width() / 2), (top_border * 0.75f) + (Title_Paint_bounds.height() / 2), Title_Paint);
        //draw buttons
        btn_Play.draw(canvas);
        //btn_Highscores.draw(canvas);
        btn_Exit.draw(canvas);
        btn_Rate.draw(canvas);

    } else if (state == LEVELMENU) {
        //draw levels

        for (int i = 0; i < Level_Buttons.length; i++) {
            Level_Buttons[i].draw(canvas);
        }
```

Comment: which view's backgroundColor do you want to change ?

Comment: I just want to add responsive rectangle or somethine like that to this code... All code of the game is in the MainGame.java.

Comment: Where is **the view** that you want to change his background?

Comment: I added code in main post.

Answer (score 0):

And there is a code for level_button.java

```
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

import com.neurondigital.nudge.Button;
import com.neurondigital.nudge.Screen;
import com.neurondigital.nudge.Sprite;

public class level_button extends Button {
int TopScore = 0;
boolean islocked = true;
Paint level_paint;
Screen screen;
Sprite lock, unlock;

public level_button(String text, int dpSize, Typeface font, int color, float x, float y, float radius, int BackColor, Screen screen, boolean world, Paint level_paint) {
    super(text, dpSize, font, color, x, y, radius, BackColor, screen, world);
    this.level_paint = level_paint;
    this.screen = screen;
    lock = new Sprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(screen.getResources(), R.drawable.lock), radius / 2);
    unlock = new Sprite(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(screen.getResources(), R.drawable.unlock), radius / 2);

}

public void setTopScore(int TopScore) {
    this.TopScore = TopScore;
    if (TopScore > 0) {
        setLock(false);
    }
}

public void setLock(boolean islocked) {
    this.islocked = islocked;
}

public String IntegerToScore(int score) {
    return ((double) score / 1000) + screen.getResources().getString(R.string.time_suffix);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    if (islocked)
        lock.draw(canvas, x + width - lock.getWidth(), y + height - lock.getHeight());
    else {
        if (TopScore == 0)
            unlock.draw(canvas, x + width - unlock.getWidth(), y + height - unlock.getHeight());
        else
            canvas.drawText(IntegerToScore(TopScore), x + (width / 2) - level_paint.measureText(IntegerToScore(TopScore)) * 0.5f, y + height + level_paint.getTextSize(), level_paint);
    }
}
}
```